# ImportError: cannot import name 'CRS' from 'pyproj'

Tags: pyproj, rioxarray

I am getting the following error message when I am importing the rioxarray library.
In my conda env I have installed the pyproj version 3.1.0

Has anyone came across the same issue?
How can I fix it?

Below is the code that I am trying to run.

```
import xarray
import rioxarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping

xds = xarray.open_dataset("NDVI_1km_V2/2020/c_gls_NDVI_202001010000_GLOBE_PROBAV_V2.2.1.nc")
xds = xds[['NDVI', 'TIME_GRID']].transpose('time', 'lat', 'lon')

xds.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim='lon', y_dim="lat", inplace=True)

xds.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)

geodf = geopandas.read_file("Africa/POLYGON.shp")

clipped = xds.rio.clip(geodf.geometry.apply(mapping), geodf.crs)
clipped.to_netcdf(path="NDVI_1km_V2/2020/rio_clipped.nc", format="NETCDF4")
```

And here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/.../main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import rioxarray
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/africrs2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rioxarray/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import rioxarray.raster_array  # noqa
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/africrs2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rioxarray/raster_array.py", line 27, in <module>
    from rioxarray.crs import crs_from_user_input
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/africrs2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rioxarray/crs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pyproj import CRS
ImportError: cannot import name 'CRS' from 'pyproj' (/opt/anaconda3/envs/africrs2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please include the actual full code line that leads to this error.

Comment: Thanks! The error happens if you remove everything but the `import rioxarray` line, right? How *exactly* did you install rioxarray and pyproj?

Comment: Exactly. I have installed inside a conda environment using ```conda install -c conda-forge rioxarray```

Comment: Cheers! And you did not install pyproj manually?

Comment: No I didn't, I assume it was installed as dependent.

Comment: Yeah it should, maybe there is a bug in the conda package. Can you try running `from pyproj import CRS` in a clean Python session? If it does not work, what does `import pyproj; pyproj.__version__;` say?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is related to this:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658167/cannot-import-name-crs-from-pyproj-for-using-the-osmnx-library
- https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#how-to-fix-it

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
```